# HTAccess Redirect Advertisement

Tags: html, .htaccess, mobile

Looking for a .htaccess code for mobile based redirects.  The plan is to have the user get redirected ONCE every 24 hours to a website called yyy.org.

What I need is to check if they meet the mobile criteria.  If they do, check if they have a cookie.  If both is true, give them a cookie and redirect them to the yyy.org site.

The condition for the rewrite:

```
    $RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|blackberry|brew|cldc|docomo|htc|j2me|micromax|lg|midp|mot|motorola|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|opera.mini|palm|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windows.ce) [NC]
```

Other possible code: this isn't finished:

```
   RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}:1440]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}:1440]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|blackberry|brew|cldc|docomo|htc|j2me|micromax|lg|midp|mot|motorola|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|opera.mini|palm|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windows.ce) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://yyyy.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Is this possible and what would be the remaining code?

Answer (score 0):

if they are mobile clients you can redirect them to a local script and then check the cookie inside the script and act according the cookie value, but as user i find annoying that i get redirected to a page that i didn't request

also you can use rewritecond for cookies like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

more info about cookies and htacces: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#Cookie_Manipulation_Tests_mod_rewrite

Comment: I know its annoying but thats what I need